# Send monit alert to log file instead of email

Tags: monit

I am using monit for several processes. But I do not want to sent an email when there is an issue, whereas I need it to log it to a file.

Can this be done?

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Monit: 5.6

Current process config:

```
check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

*[Disabling alerts for some services](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Disabling-alerts-for-some-service)*

Comment: That just disables the alerts. That doesn't cover the ability to log to a file.

Comment: Look in `/var/log/monit` and `/var/log/messages`

Comment: I have neither :/

Comment: @jshthornton Then please add pertinent details like: operating system and version, version of Monit, etc.

Comment: Updated to give some more details.